# How to check if an any kind of component reference's value is null or not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Following method is supposed to do: Set any kind of _obj to _val and return true if it is null, otherwise false.

The method is:

```
    public bool SetAndCheckIfNull<T>(ref T _obj, T _val)
    {

        // <summary> Sets _obj to _val, after that if _obj is null then it returns true, otherwise false, If an error occurs returns true

        try
        {

            _obj = _val;
            return ReferenceEquals(_val, null);

        }
        catch
        {

            return true;

        }

    }
```

When i set _val to a component that is attached to a GameObject, _obj correspondingly sets to _val, _obj is not null however methods itself always returns false for some reason.

What i am asking for is: how can i make this method to return true if _val is null ?
Thanks.

Comment: If (_val == null) return true; ?? it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the null-coalescing operator.

You can learn more about it in the documentation: [The null-coalescing operator C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

Comment: Unfortunately Unity does not support C# 8.0

Comment: Alright, you can remove your try cacht (because it dont have a real use) and what you can do is in your function SetAndCheckIfNull : return _val is null; normally it should work because unity support 7.3 if it dosen't work juste do : return _val == null;